# How to access the current response's status_code in Flask's teardown_request?

Tags: python, flask

I'm interfacing with an internal logging system and I'd like to obtain the current response's `status_code` from within Flask's `teardown_request` callback: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request. I like that it is guaranteed to be called and I can get all the other information needed for my purposes.

I can access the current response and it's `status_code` if I connect to the `request_finished` signal:

```
def request_finished_listener(sender, response):
    print(response.status_code)

request_finished.connect(request_finished_listener)
```

But I'd like to do all my data collection within the `teardown_request` if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't.  `teardown_request` is called as cleanup after the response is generated, it does not have access to the response.  You should use the `request_finished` signal or `after_request` decorator if you need access to the response from within Flask.  `teardown_request` is only intended for cleaning up resources.

If you need to log something about the response and absolutely don't want to use `request_finished` or `after_request`, you'll have to wrap the Flask app in WSGI middleware.